# C++ Lambda Local Variable Capturing Error

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying to use a lambda expression to make inorderTraversal function reusable, and I am having the following error while trying to capture the local parameters of printStandartDeviation function: No viable conversion from '(lambda at [...]/AVLTree.cpp:[...])' to 'void (*)(AVLTree::TreeNode *)'.

```
void AVLTree::printStandartDeviation() {
    int totalWordCount = 0, totalWordFrequencies = 0;
    inorderTraversal(root, [&totalWordCount, &totalWordFrequencies](TreeNode *tNode) {
        totalWordCount++;
        totalWordFrequencies += tNode->frequency;
    });
}

void AVLTree::inorderTraversal(TreeNode *tNode, void (*visit)(TreeNode *)) {
    if (tNode == nullptr) {
        return;
    } else {
        inorderTraversal(tNode->left, visit);
        visit(tNode);
        inorderTraversal(tNode->right, visit);
    }
}
```

It fixes if I make my local variables static or make them global, but I do not want to do either actually.

I am also open to alternative solutions as well instead of using lambda.

I would be grateful if you can help.

Comment: Can you change `inorderTraversal`?

Comment: Using this kind of function pointer is almost useless. Unless you provide a way of passing in an additional context pointer (`void*`) that is also passed to the function, there's no way of having any state for the logic in the function the function pointer points to. The simplest way to make this work would be to make `inorderTraversal` a function template and use a template parameter type for `visit` instead of a function pointer type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda is not a function pointer. A non-capturing lambda has a conversion to function pointer but one with captures not. It is somewhat similar to the difference between a pointer to free function and pointer to member function where the pointer to member function alone is of little use. You need an object to call a member function. Here you also need the data, the captured variables, to call the lambda, its not just a function.

You do not need a function pointer. Simply pass the lambda as it is, and because the lambdas type has no name, make the method a template to make this work:

```
template <typename F>
void AVLTree::inorderTraversal(TreeNode *tNode, F&& visit) {
    // all the same
}
```